# Ajax submit form not working the first url app.icontact

Tags: ajax, forms, submit

I need to send the form details to icontact page but its not going what to do

here is my code

```
 <script>
function submitForm() {
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php', data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
    $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
}});

return false;
}
</script>
<script>
function submitForm() {
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'zohoprocess.php', data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
    $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
}});

return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have duplicated the same function why? i think you want to send data to two different URLs

Comment: why submitForm() twice ?

Comment: yes i want to send data to two different urls is there any way

Comment: I think you are over complicating the process. what i got from your script that first function will signup and second will show data on that bases.

Comment: yes brother but i need to do it both is there will be any way other than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Asynchronous request like

```
function SubmitForm()
{ 
var formdata=$('#ContactForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
      type:'POST', 
      url: 'https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php',
      data:formdata, 
      success: function(response)
               {
               $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);

               $.ajax({
                     type:'POST', 
                     url: 'zohoprocess.php', 
                     data:formdata, 
                     success: function(response)
                             {
                             $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
                             }
                      });

               },
       error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
               {
                  alert('request failed');
               }
      }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need two functions for this. Its getting over complicated.

> ```
>  <script>
> function submitForm() {
> $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php',
> ```
>
> data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
>
> ```
>     $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
> }});
> //alert and check here
> return false;
> }
> </script>
> ```

Make sure this method is called on submit button click and that should do. Keep an alert in onSuccess function to check that response is correct. Also double check that `div` u are trying to access is present visible inside the `onSuccess` function call.

Thanks.